# Basic JavaScript Algorithm, Fibonacci series

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

**Sum all the odd numbers of the Fibonacci Series up to and including the given number.**

I can't figure out the syntax for  the problem I'm having. The problem, The for loop, loop ends when it is greater than or equal to the value of the `num`,  instead I want it to end with the, to be generated values of the `start`.

Is there any way to make it work?

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var odd = [1]; // Odd numbers of the Fibonacci series
  var start = [0,1]; // Fibonacci series
  // Generating the series and filtering out the odd numbers 
  for(i=1;i<num;i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum = start[i] + start[i-1];
    start.push(sum);
    if(sum%2 != 0) {
      odd.push(sum);
    }
  } 
   // Generating sum of the odd numbers
 var main = 0; // sum of the odd numbers
 for(i=0;i<odd.length;i++) {
   main += odd[i]
 }
  console.log(start);console.log(odd);return main
}

sumFibs(4);
```

Comment: instead you want to end with ...? missing something there

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: It is looping until it reaches the value of num. I want it to stop when it reaches the value of num but in the start.  For ex - If the passed number is 13, it is going to generate 13 numbers, it shouldn't do that, it is supposed to stop when it reaches 13 in the start.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that if I understand correctly

```
while(start.length<num)
 {
        your code will be here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with two arrays, maybe it's less confusing to work with one and use Array.prototype.reduce to sum only the odd values.

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var fib = [0, 1];
  var sum = 0;
  var i = 2;
  while (true) {
    sum = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
    if (sum > num) {
      break;
    }
    fib.push(sum);
    i++;
  }
  return fib.reduce(function(v0, v) {
    return v0 + (v % 2 === 0 ? 0 : v);
  }, 0);
}
```

Have a look at my attempt at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/copet80/xejz4ka2/

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this a Project Euler question? 
If I understand the problem right then your problem is  in the for loop. More specific in its condition. The for loop in your case will repeat itself so many times how num is -1 because you start at i = 1 and i < num. So in you case it will repeat istself 12 times and reach a much higher number than 13 if I understand the problem right.

First of, Im a beginner but I was taught that you use a for loop if you know how many times something has to repeat. In this case you dont know how many times you have to repeat the for loop because you dont know when you reach the number 13.

In this case a while loop would be better I think and you set the condition for you number. So for example:

```
while(sum<=num){}
```

or like somone before me said:

```
while (true){
   if(sum<num){
     break;
  }
```

This 2 codes will end if the SUM will exceed 13. I belive you dont want the Fibonaci number too exceed 13. In this scenario you have to make other conditions but im feeling its project euler i wont give tha answer here.

Again. you have the loop condition to end if the fib number exceeds 13. Your code looks for 13-1 fibonacci numbers.